# how I can Modify this code

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I'm using this function to send a request to a server and receive JSON response in an NSDictionary.

```
- (void)performRequest:(NSString *)aRequest
{
    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,aRequest];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: string];
    NSLog(@"string%@",string);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSDictionary * greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:NULL];
             NSLog(@"%@",greeting2);
         }
     }];
}
```

What I want is to modify it so that it remains a function sending service URL and a separate one where the JSON response comes at a NSDictionary so you can reuse them in other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the networking introduced by iOS 7: **NSURLSession**. This is the networking code I use in a project. But I would suggest you to use **AFNetworking** instead. That will save you more time on it. It depends on what you want in your application.

```
+ (void)requestOperationWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                       withUrl:(NSString *)url
                        header:(NSDictionary *)header
                        params:(NSDictionary *)params
                    completion:(FHCompletionResultBlock)completion {
FHNetworking *network = [FHNetworking shareNetworking];
NSData *bodyData;
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
if (!jsonError) {
    bodyData = data;
}

// prepare http request header and body data fields
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
for (NSString *key in header.allKeys) {
    [request setValue:header[key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];
}
[request setHTTPMethod:method];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
[[network.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

    if (jsonError)
        completion(nil, jsonError);
    else {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        if (httpResponse.statusCode >= 400) {

            if (json[@"code"] && json[@"error"]) {
                NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Error" code:[json[@"code"] integerValue] userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: NSLocalizedString(json[@"error"], nil)}];
                completion(nil, error);
            }
            else {
                NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Error" code:-1 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: NSLocalizedString(@"Unknown error", nil)}];
                completion(nil, error);
            }
        }
        else {
            completion(json, nil);
        }
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}] resume];
```

}

Comment: BTW, I captured NSURLSession and NSURLSessionConfiguration into the shared manager just in case you can not figure that out.

Comment: Here is the definition of the completion block: `typedef void (^FHCompletionResultBlock)(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error);`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method to take a `completionHandler` parameter, itself:

```
- (void)performRequest:(NSString *)aRequest completionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,aRequest];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil) { 
            NSError *parseError;
            NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                           options:0
                                                                             error:&parseError];
            completionHandler(responseObject, parseError);
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Now you can call it and supply whatever you want in the completion handler:

```
[self performRequest:requestString completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (responseObject) {
        // everything is good; use your NSDictionary here
    } else {
        // handle error here
    }
}];
```